# OpenCV unhandled exception

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, x86, unhandled-exception

I am a hardware (arduino hobbyist) programmer trying to get into OpenCV but struggling with a random error.
I have been following Adam Hacks youtibe guide to OpenCV and up to very recently it has worked great. I had compiled OpenCV as 32bit as the prebuilt was only available in x64 and my intended application (driving a set of servos via a FT232H usb to I2C adapter) was in 32 bit.

I typed in his code for "Using OpenCV and Haar Cascades to Detect Faces in a Video [C++]" and it worked fine (see below). It identified my face (some of the time) and drew a box round it. Yeah I was very happy.

The code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


/* Include D2XX header*/
#include "ftd2xx.h"
/* Include libMPSSE header */
#include "libMPSSE_i2c.h"
#include "FT232.h"

using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    //FT232 ft232;
    //ft232.setUpFT232H();

    double scale = 1.0;
    CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
    faceCascade.load("C:\\OpenCV32\\etc\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;
    for (;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        Mat grayscale;
        cvtColor(frame, grayscale, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        resize(grayscale, grayscale, Size(grayscale.size().width / scale, grayscale.size().height / scale));

        vector  <Rect> faces;

        faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, Size(30, 30));

        for (Rect area : faces) {
            Scalar drawColor = Scalar(255, 0, 0);
            rectangle(frame, Point(cvRound(area.x * scale), cvRound(area.y * scale)),
                Point(cvRound((area.x + area.width-1)*scale), cvRound((area.y + area.height - 1) * scale)), drawColor);
        }

        imshow("Webcam Frame", frame);

        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then with no intentional changes on my part other that swapping about from one haarcascade to another the program stopped working and threw an unhandled error.

`Unhandled exception at 0x76979862 in OpenCV_Nerf.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00EFF428. occurred`

in this part of the system.cpp code

```
void error( const Exception& exc )
{
#ifdef CV_ERROR_SET_TERMINATE_HANDLER
    {
        cv::AutoLock lock(getInitializationMutex());
        if (!cv_terminate_handler_installed)
        {
            if (param_setupTerminateHandler)
                cv_old_terminate_handler = std::set_terminate(cv_terminate_handler);
            cv_terminate_handler_installed = true;
        }
        cv_terminate_handler_exception = exc;
    }
#endif

    if (customErrorCallback != 0)
        customErrorCallback(exc.code, exc.func.c_str(), exc.err.c_str(),
                            exc.file.c_str(), exc.line, customErrorCallbackData);
    else if (param_dumpErrors)
    {
        dumpException(exc);
    }

    if(breakOnError)
    {
        static volatile int* p = 0;
        *p = 0;
    }

    throw exc;
#ifdef __GNUC__
# if !defined __clang__ && !defined __APPLE__
    // this suppresses this warning: "noreturn" function does return [enabled by default]
    __builtin_trap();
    // or use infinite loop: for (;;) {}
# endif
#endif
}
```

the error box pointing to the very last line.

The camera still functions and I have narrowed it down to the line
`faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, Size(30, 30));`

Build output: (I don't remember the warnings about loss of data first few time,, but I can't be sure)

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: OpenCV_Nerf, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>D:\Vincent\Documents\Programming\Visual Studio Projects\OpenCV_Nerf\Source.cpp(32,93): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to '_Tp', possible loss of data
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Tp=int
1>        ]
1>D:\Vincent\Documents\Programming\Visual Studio Projects\OpenCV_Nerf\Source.cpp(32,60): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to '_Tp', possible loss of data
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Tp=int
1>        ]
1>OpenCV_Nerf.vcxproj -> D:\Vincent\Documents\Programming\Visual Studio Projects\OpenCV_Nerf\Debug\OpenCV_Nerf.exe
1>Done building project "OpenCV_Nerf.vcxproj".
```

Debug output (last bit as it was over character count)

```
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_95bdb3a23d6478de\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'
The thread 0x31a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1f70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3668 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3698 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3a34 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x374 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3288 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x35bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x348c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3968 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1068 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1ef8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3a30 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x184c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x37f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x18b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3380 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3bf8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'OpenCV_Nerf.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvproc.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
Exception thrown at 0x76979862 in OpenCV_Nerf.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00FCF7EC.
Unhandled exception at 0x76979862 in OpenCV_Nerf.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00FCF7EC.
```

I am completely stumped and would really appreciate any help or pointers I could get.

Regards

Comment: Try with these face `default` and `alt2` haar cascades from here, https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades.

Comment: Thanks but nope. I tried several, I don't know if this was related to the error but it happened after swapping to tree_eyeglasses. Now it doesn't matter what I pick. I'm going to try to rewrite/make the whole thing, see if I can recreate it. It worked initially.

Comment: I have rewritten it into a new solution, exactly as before. Worked fine. Closed VS down, came back reopened it and now it fails with the same error. I did notice in the bottom left it said user configuration overridden by editorconfig?? Back to square one.

Comment: working now????!!!!